# What is the probability of a code having no red peg and at least two pegs of the same colour?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The game of Mastermind requires players to select a “code” consisting of an ordered sequence of four pegs, each of which may be of any of six colors: red, green, blue, yellow, white, and black, with repetitions allowed.

**What is the probability of a code having no red peg and at least two pegs of the same colour?**

My first step was to work out the number of ways were two pegs occur of the same colour so I did

$6^4 - P(6,4) = 936$

Ways a red can occur $= P(6,1)$

Ways a red cannot occur $= 6^4 - P(6,1) = 1290$

No red peg and at least two pegs of the same colour $= 1290 – 936 = 354$

The probability will therefore be $\frac{354}{1296}$

Is this correct?

Comment: You have six choices four times to make a code, so the total number is $6^4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of codes is $6^4=1296$  To count the ones with no reds and two of the same colors we will count the ones with four non-red pegs and subtract the ones with four different colors.  There are $5^4=625$ codes with no red pegs.  Of those, if we want four different colors we have five choices for the first peg, four for the second, three for the third, and two for the fourth, for a total of $5\cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2=120.$  The chance a random code has no reds and two the same is then $\frac {625-120}{1296}=\frac {505}{1296}\approx 38.966\%$